# Server based error handling in redux-form with react and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-form

I am not sure what my exact questions is because I am fairly new to react redux and the various plugins involved.

My setup is using the following packages:

```
"axios": "^0.17.0",
"react": "^16.1.1",
"react-dom": "^16.1.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-scripts": "1.0.17",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-form": "^7.1.2",
"redux-promise": "^0.5.3"
```

I have a component that uses a form to post data to a server endpoint.

Depending on the result I want to show form level validation eg: `username does not exist` I would like to show a form level error. Or if I get a `404` response I would like to be able to handle this too.

I currently have my component linked to the `redux-form` library using the standard method at the bottom of the file. My validation function runs as expected before the form submits.

My form has a `onSubmit` attribute that resolves to a returned promise. This promise is pulled from an action creator that makes the server request.

I have read through the [`redux-form` docs](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/) and it seems like I am looking for the [SubmissionError](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/submissionerror.md/).

When I throw this error in my `onSubmit` function I get the intended behaviour however then my action creator does not run.

```
    onSubmit(values) {
        throw new SubmissionError({_error: 'test' })            
        return this.props.loginUser(values));
    }
```

If I chain a `.then()` from the returned promise and throw the `SubmissionError` here I get another error.

```
    onSubmit(values) {
        return this.props.loginUser(values).then(() => { throw new SubmissionError({_error: 'test' })});
    }
```

I have ready many answers and none fit my situation. Some are similar and I have been able to get this far because of that however I am still unable to trigger the form level error dependant on the server response as intended.

### LoginForm:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { loginUser }  from '../../../actions';

import InputField from '../Fields/InputField.js';

import { VIEWS } from '../../../routes';

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(values) {
        return this.props.loginUser(values);
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="auth-form">
                <div className="auth-block">
                    <div className="auth-content">
                        <h1>Specify with Certainty</h1>
                        <h1>{this.props.error}</h1>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                            <Field
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Email"
                                type="email"
                                component={InputField}
                            />
                            <Field
                                name="password"
                                placeholder="Password"
                                type="password"
                                component={InputField}
                            />
                            <button className="action submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                            <div className="checkbox">
                                <label htmlFor="remember">
                                    <Field
                                        name="remember"
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        component={InputField}
                                    />
                                    <span>Remember me</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div className="register-promt">
                        <p>Don't have an account?</p>
                        <Link to={VIEWS.REGISTER}>Register Now &raquo;</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function validate(values) {

    const errors = {};

    // Need to validate email here

    if(!values.email) {
        errors.email = "Enter an email";
    }

    if(!values.password) {
        errors.password = "Enter a password";
    }

    return errors;
}

const formData = {
    validate,
    form: 'LoginForm'
};

const connected = connect(null, { loginUser })(Login);

export default reduxForm(formData)(connected);
```

### Action creator

```js
export function loginUser(values) {

    const request = axios({
        method: 'post',
        crossdomain: true,
        url: API.LOGIN,
        data: values
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('hello world');
        throw new SubmissionError({_error: 'testing'});
    });

    return {
        type: LOGIN_USER,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

I Think I am missing something small here but very vital.

### How can I pass errors to my form component based on a server response using the `redux-form` library in the intended way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since `this.props.loginUser(values)` returns an action `{ type, payload }`. Try with `payload` like this: `onSubmit(values) { return this.props.loginUser(values).payload; }`

Comment: @NinhPham Thanks for the comment but this did not work. I have resulted to moving my promise to my component instead of the action creator. It works but I would prefer to have it the way it was presented in this question.